# Plotting a 4D Dynamical System

Tags: dynamical-systems, graphing-functions

Suppose I have a 4D dynamical system. Each axis has a fixed point, and there are orbits connecting the fixed points. It looks something like this:

[image]

Each $Q_i$ is a fixed point on each axis of a four-dimensional coordinate space. I believe I have found parameters of my dynamical system that leads to the behavior in the picture. However, I'd like to see if these parameters work numerically. I'd like to see if I start near the $Q_1-Q_2-Q_3$ plane, I stay there for all time, and if I start near the Each $Q_i$ is a fixed point on each axis of a four-dimensional coordinate space. I believe I have found parameters of my dynamical system that leads to the behavior in the picture. However, I'd like to see if these parameters work numerically. I'd like to see if I start near the $Q_2-Q_3-Q_4$ plane, I stay there for all time. Essentially, in the first case, the 4th dimension value tends to $0$ asymptotically, and in the latter, the 1st dimensional value tends to $0$. I should therefore have 2 basin of attractions for each plane. However, since this is a 4D system, this is not easy to plot and show numerically.

What is the best way to plot numerically the 4D system so that I can observe that I have 2 basin of attractions, each one exhibiting a heteroclinic cycle in each plane?

Comment: Do you whether the line connecting the attractors are straight or can they also be curved. Also do you know the local behavior of the dynamics at the attractors, a.k.a. the Jacobian matrix, and how many stable eigenvalues these have?

Comment: @fibonatic straight or curved is fine. I know the Jacobian matrix at each fixed point. At Q1 and Q4, there are 2 stable eigenvalues, at Q2 there is 3, and at Q3 there is 2

Comment: I suggest to plot each coordinate independently as a graph "$x_i$ vs $t$ (time)". I think in Guckenheimer-Holmes system this plot is pretty self-explanatory and you should expect something similar: http://images.scholarpedia.org/w/images/f/f0/Gholmes_time_series_cycle.jpg (of course if you don't add noise ;) )